# Can I extract a nested structure of a type in Typescript to use it for declaring a new type?

Tags: typescript

Think of a type defined as follows:

```
type primaryType = {
  level1: {
    level12: {
      a: string
      b: string
      c: string
    }
  }
  ... 
}
```

Now I want to create a new type which is inferred from the property with key `level12` and hence, it will implicitly have properties `a`, `b` and `c`:

```
// Something like this (notation is not valid, used just to visualize the idea):
type inferredType = primaryType.level1.level12

// Not this:
type inferredType = {
  a: string
  b: string
  c: string
}
```

I scanned the [utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html), but could not figure a transformation out for such a purpose.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you can do :

```
type inferredType = primaryType['level1']['level12']
```